# php find string from file starting with xxx word till word yyy

Tags: php, preg-match-all

It's a log file contained lines like this

```
...
Mar  1 03:34:24 domain sshd[19178]: Failed password for root from 222.186.55.230 port 3005 ssh2
...
```

I would like to put in array every line where user fail and in other array lines where user succeed Lines started with xxx=Failed or succeed till yyy=ssh2 so then I could get ip from both array with:

```
preg_match_all("/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/", $securelogfile, $matches);
```

and get the difference ip in a new array. I'm terrible at regex what I was trying is just wasting my time.

Comment: You need to put braces around: `/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/`

Comment: well, it's working without them but I'm going to assume your respecting rules @ThomasKilian . any ideas how to get 5 words left and 3 words right ,from ip, to get something like :   Failed password for root from 222.186.55.230 port 3005 ssh2 ?

Comment: ^(\w+ +){5}((\d+\.){3}\d+)((\w+ +){3}\w+) will do

Comment: What should I have with that regex @ThomasKilian ? Well is just returning the same as my preg_match_all above, just ips

Comment: You asked for matching 5 words + IP + 3 words. That's it.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I'm writing it like this preg_match_all("/^(\w+ +){5}((\d+\.){3}\d+)((\w+ +){1}\w+)/", $securelogfile, $matches);  Trying to get 1 word to the right, but it return and empty array, also happens with 3 words to theright. Is this (\w+ +) getting words (group of characters) and 1 space right?  should I replace spaces with /s ?

Comment: You can test the regex here: https://regex101.com It seems my regex needs a trailing blank. The site gives a lot of help to modify the regex to your needs.

Comment: `^(\w+ +){5}((\d+\.){3}\d+)( +\w+){3}` seems to fit better (I just tested with above site)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKilian , also very useful website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question as @ThomasKilian did . I use for failed:

```
 preg_match_all("/^(\b(Failed)\b\s+)(\w+ +){4}((\d+\.){3}\d+)( +\w+){3}/", $securelogfile, $matches);
```

for Failed log lines and:

```
 preg_match_all("/^(\b(Success)\b\s+)(\w+ +){4}((\d+\.){3}\d+)( +\w+){3}/", $securelogfile, $matches);
```

Keep in mind that first {4} indicate 4 words counting after "Failed or Succeed"

That give arrays where I should I should get clean IPs and then get the difference.